# Some white blocks appear in the activity after the webview load data

Tags: android, webview, block, cardview

I develop the activity in android 7.0 OS, and some times the white blocks appear in the status bar and navigate bar. Who can help me to fix it.

Normal activity on left, activity with white blocks on right:

[image]    [image]

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="@dimen/normal_margin_48"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_gameinfo_detail_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_web"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_margin_8"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardElevation="3dp"
            app:contentPadding="@dimen/normal_margin_8">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wv_original_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_space"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/view_game_info_detail_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be hardware accelerate is the reason.